# Symfony OneupUploaderBundle how to link the uploaded files to the entity

Tags: symfony, oneupuploaderbundle

I am using [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle), with jQuery File Upload. After the files are selected, they are uploaded and renamed by the bunudle. The problem I am facing to, is from the validation of my form(entity) how can I know the list of files that have been uploaded ? I don't know which kind of parts of code can be useful for this question as I have just followed their [guide](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/frontend_blueimp.md) but I can edit if needed.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I've built is to add the picture filename, via the EventListener used for the file posting, in a text file, then explode the text file in an array from the controller (form validation) and move the pictures files to their final location. If someone as a better solution... Do not hesitate!